# The file name or path doesn't exist or used by other program while writing Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am trying to create an Excel file and write some data to it.
Here is the code I am using.

```
using excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
excel.Application xlapp;
excel.Workbook xlworkbook;
excel.Worksheet xlworksheet;
object misvalue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

xlapp = new excel.ApplicationClass();
xlworkbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Add(misvalue);

xlworksheet = (excel.Worksheet)xlworkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlworksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Muneeb Hassan Soomro";
xlworkbook.SaveAs("csharp-excelwrite.xls",excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,misvalue,misvalue,misvalue,misvalue,excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,misvalue,misvalue,misvalue,misvalue,misvalue);
//xlworkbook.SaveAs("csharp-Excel.xls", excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
xlworkbook.Close(true, misvalue, misvalue);
xlapp.Quit();
```

I get an exception on the `xlworkbook.saveas()` call. says:

> The file name or path doesn't exist or used by other program

What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: So, do you get any exception or what?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not just making a csv?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: yes i am getting exception on the function of saveas.
I am actually learning how to write a file in excel!

Comment: @Meiyoki i have already exported the data to csv file.
But want to learn excel file writing using interop library.

Comment: xlworkbook.SaveAs("csharp-excelwrite.xls",excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, **ref** misvalue ...

Comment: @CodyGray yes i edited it! 
i am getting an exception on the saveas function!

Comment: Could you please just try with excel file name "C:\\csharp-excelwrite.xls" insted of "csharp-excelwrite.xls" in the first parameter of xlworkbook.SaveAs() method and let me know is it works or not. @Muneeb Hasan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from one of your comments on another answer I finally got the exception text (This information should have been included in the question!)

> The file name or path doesn't exist or used by other program

The solution should be simple: Specify a full path in the `SaveAs` call, not only a file name. How should Excel know in which folder it should save the file otherwise?

Comment: you are right @cremon

Comment: @cremor you are right, i gave the path and now it is making an excel file!

Comment: You should mark it as answer so that other having the same issue can find it helpful @Muneeb Hassan

Comment: i was about to mark it but went away! 
Although thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this line

```
xlworkbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Add(misvalue);
```

to this line:

```
xlworkbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
```

and the SaveAs:

```
workBook.SaveAs("csharp-excelwrite.xls", XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

Comment: still getting exception
The file name or path doesn't exist or used by other program

Comment: Maybe your file is open by Excel, in task panel in the processes tab close all of the open tasks and change this line: xlworkbook.Close(true, misvalue, misvalue); to this: workBook.Close(true, "csharp-excelwrite.xls", null);

Comment: this solution is working - tested just now

Answer (score 0):

So i suggest you to use [excellibrary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) for Excel file writing

You can find a details on [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp)

Comment: i have to add this project to my project to use its functionality?

Comment: you just need to add the reference of this dll in your project.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
object format = excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal;
object sv = excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive;
object filename = "csharp-excelwrite.xls";

xlworkbook.SaveAs(ref filename,ref format,
ref misvalue,ref misvalue,ref misvalue,
ref misvalue,ref sv,ref misvalue,ref misvalue,
ref misvalue,ref misvalue,ref misvalue);
```

it is working for me with Word application for example

```
object readOnly = isReadonly;
object isVisible = true;
object missing = WordConst.Missing;
wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing,
                          ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                          ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                          ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing, 
                          ref missing, ref missing);
```

Comment: giving error.
Argument should not be passed with the ref key word.

Comment: well, it works with MS Word in my application